# Understanding C function arguments

Tags: c

I have this function declaration:

```
void gaussian_blur
(
    const unsigned char* const inputChannel,
    unsigned char* const outputChannel,
    const float* const filter
) 
{..}
```

I'm new to C. I've gone through basic tutorials and understand the concept of pointers and constants, but I can't make sense what is meant by this argument list.

Can anyone explain what this means?

Comment: If you understood pointers, where is the problem?

Comment: What is `const unsigned char* const` ? Is it immutable variable of type `unsigned char* const` ? What type is it ?

Comment: this means, that the pointer ist constant and the target data ist constant as well.

Comment: Are you confused about the *types*--as many of the comments assume--or about the intended meaning of the arguments? Or both?

Comment: About the types. Apparently I did'n understand pointers as good as poitroae does. I was absolutely missing the thing called `constant pointer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const unsigned char* const inputChannel;
```

Input channel is a constant pointer to a constant unsigned char.

```
unsigned char* const outputChannel;
```

OutputChannel is a constant pointer to a unsigned char.

```
const float* const filter
```

filter is a constant pointer to a constant float.

> Constant pointer  - The address held by the pointer variable cannot be
>   changed.
>
> Constant data - The data , is treated as readonly/constant and cannot
>   be modified.

Comment: @Alex no problem anytime , you will understand better if you try to modify contents of const pointer / const data , and see the warnings/errors the compiler will throw at you

Answer (score 3):

Read right to left:

```
const unsigned char* const inputChannel
```

`inputChannel` is a constant pointer to an `unsigned char` constant.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the info link of the [c](/questions/tagged/c) tag, which you tag this question with, scroll down to

> Important notes that may save you time

And you'll see a link to the [Spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) which is very helpful for deciphering the meanings of things you don't understand in C:

The basics of it are to read the name of the variable, then move your way around right and then left one element at a time. In this case because there's nothing to the right of your variable you just move left:

```
 inputChannel,                           // inputChannel is a
 const inputChannel,                     // constant
 * const inputChannel,                   // pointer
 char* const inputChannel,               // to a char
 unsigned char* const inputChannel,      // which is unsigned
 const unsigned char* const inputChannel // which is constant
```

So it's a constant pointer and what it points to (an unsigned char) is also constant. Pretty easy.

If that's too much you can always cheat too, throw what you don't understand into here: http://cdecl.org/ and it spits it back in English (usually)

Comment: @Alex - NP, it's a handly link, just keep in mind if you're reading code offline/not at a computer it's important to know how to do it by hand.